# Трудности перевода с C++ на Python

Tags: python-3.x

В языке программирования C++ оператор for очень МОЩНОЕ и ГИБКОЕ средство.
Поэтому перевод его на другие языки программирования подчас вызывает большие сложности.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше перевести на язык-Python следующую конструкцию языка-C++:

```
int length = 10

char test_m[length] = {'.', '.', '#', '#', '.', '.', '#', '#', '.', '.', }

for(int x=0; x<length; x++)
    cout << "x: " << x << " ->  sym: " << test_m[x] << endl;
    if (test_m[x] == '#')
        # --------------------------------------------------------------
        for(; x<length && test_m[x] == '#'; x++)
            cout << "x: " << x << " ->  sym: " << test_m[x] << endl;
        # --------------------------------------------------------------

// Вывод:
// c: 0 ->  sym: .
// c: 1 ->  sym: .
// c: 2 ->  sym: #
// c: 3 ->  sym: #
// c: 4 ->  sym: .
// c: 5 ->  sym: .
// c: 6 ->  sym: #
// c: 7 ->  sym: #
// c: 8 ->  sym: .
// c: 9 ->  sym: .
```

- Я, конечно, переводил, но мои варианты как правило были ЗАПУТАННЫМИ и НЕУДОБОЧИТАЕМЫМИ!
  Может есть какие-то СТАНДАРТНЫЕ решения для подобных случаев? И они будут УДОБОВАРИМЫЕ?

Comment: А что такого особенного делает этот код? Я как-то мощИ не ощутил - for c in s print даст то же самое

Comment: - Да, конечно прошу простить, в примере забыл поставить фигурные скобки для первого оператора for!

Comment: Перепишите "форы" на "вайлы", "вайлы" переводятся в Питон как есть.

Comment: Вы ошиблись когда писали предполагаемый вывод кода.  ИМХО:  Это говорит в пользу того, что вредно (для читаемости кода) модифицировать переменную-итератор цикла внутри тела цикла. И языки, которые это запрещают - повышают читабельность. просто нужно переформулировать алгоритм в других элементарных конструкциях.

Comment: Как думаете, какую тревогу ставить сюда надо?

Comment: - Спасибо. Окончательно осознал, что в Python оператор-for не позволяет менять итератор цикла внутри самого цикла!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Питоне оператор `for` немного отличается от других языков. По сути он перебирает элементы чего-нибудь, по чему можно итерироваться. При желании в Питоне можно имитировать и ваш "вырожденный" `for` из `С++` именно через `for` с хитрым итератором, но лучше, а главное, понятнее это не будет, чем если разложить ваш `for` на:

```
while условие:
    ...
    x += 1
```

Comment: - Спасибо за информацию. Окончательно ОСОЗНАЛ, что в Python в операторе-for нельзя изменять итератор цикла внутри самого цикла. Что касается переделки, то я как раз переписывал весь этот кусок кода на C++ с помощью операторов-while. Правда получилось не так лаконично, как в C++.

Comment: @staut Да, переменную цикла в питоне менять внутри цикла без толку, на следующей итерации она примет очередное значение итератора, по которому идёт цикл, изменения забудутся.

Answer (score 0):

- Вы наверное поняли, что я переписываю уже готовый код с языка-C++ на язык-Python. Спасибо всем! С Вашей помощью, я ОКОНЧАТЕЛЬНО ОСОЗНАЛ, что пытаться сделать в операторе-for языка-Python что-то подобное языку-C++ - НЕ ПОЛУЧИТСЯ. Особое спасибо Вам CrazyElf!
- Видимо придется куски кода C++, подобные приведенному мной, тупо переписывать с помощью операторов-while. Хотя это и не так лаконично и изящно, как на языке-C++.